# Use pivot table so that I can still get the text values, and a way to split the data into multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have data in Excel that needs to be pivoted, but it should retain text values in the pivot. The values should capture the text data in the Excel data set. Not sure if this can be achieved using pivot table or if I have to use any other method

I have tried using pivot and use a slicer instead for department, but the column I am trying to bring under values, doesn't capture data that has text in it.

Source Data:

[image: Sample Input]

I need to separate this table into 3 tables (in different worksheets) based on the Department.

1st worksheet should be for finance and expected output is:

[image: Finance]

2nd worksheet should be for HR and expected output is:

[image: HR]

3rd worksheet should be for Maint and expected output is:

[image: MAINT]

Can someone suggest what is the best way?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are rows like 1/Dinner/OPA and a similar 1/Dinner/CLO -- where you have to figure out what do with the collision between OPA and CLO? – Ryan B. 1 min ago   Edit

Comment: And what version of excel are you using?

Comment: The rate column can either be number or just text. There won't be any special characters in it. And I am using office 365

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365, I'd take advantage of the pivot capabilities in Power Query rather than try to write VBA code.  If you're not familiar with power query, it will create set of reusable transformations, a lot like a macro.  But it's very much tuned for manipulating data sets and does this kind of work more effectively than macro scripts do.

The one thing that this won't like work if you have more than one row with the same Id, Type, and department.  It won't do any aggregating and will just report an error on those rows.

Assuming that many users aren't super familiar with Power query, I've made a step-by-step guide.  No offense intended if you're already used to this stuff.

1) Convert the area where your raw data is to a data table by selecting the range and then clicking 'Format as Table' on the Styles group in the Home ribbon.

[[image: 1]]

2) Open the table in Power Query by having a cell in the table selected and then going to the Data ribbon, clicking 'From Table/Range' in the 'Get & Transform Data' group.

[[image: 2]]

3) Filter Department.  I'll be using 'Maint' for the examples.  Click on the black triangle filter just like you would for filters in regular worksheets.

4) Once we've done the filtering, we don't need the department column - it won't be in our final result.  So right click the column header and choose 'Remove.'

[image]

5) Now the fun stuff.  First select the 'Type' column by clicking on the column header.  Then, navigate to the Transform Ribbon.  Find and click the 'Pivot column' button in the 'Any column' button group.  In the pop up, you will see the phrase "Use the names in column "Type" to create new columns."  If some other column is specified, cancel, make sure you have Type highlighted, and click on pivot columns again.  Set the value columns to Rate, and under advanced options choose "Don't aggregate"

[image]

and you should see the transformation!

[image]

Go back to the home tab, click 'Close and load' and the result will be added into a new worksheet.

[image]

So you can repeat this process for each department and get the tables you need.

As you enter new rows into your raw data, the three dependent tables will be all updated with the new information when you click Refresh All on the data tab, when you open the spreadsheet, or you can select refresh from the right click context menu on each table.